# Function in Where clause inside Inline Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I do this, it is not good correct?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS TABLE AS
   SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Warehouse = fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId)
```

Ideally I want to do this, but this is not allowed for ITVF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS TABLE AS
   SET @Warehouse = fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId)
   SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Warehouse = @Warehouse
```

I don't want to use MSTVF because it cannot be optimized by the query optimizer.  In the end I use this work-around:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS TABLE AS
   SELECT * FROM fn_Inventory(fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId))
```

The fn_Inventory accepts @Warehouse as parameter and queries Inventory table using the parameter, thus avoid the issue.  Is there no standard pattern for handling this situation?

Comment: Why you don't like the first version? How do you have defined the `fn_Inventory`?

Comment: Try `... WHERE Warehouse = dbo.fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId)`

Comment: Sorry I was unclear.  "Function inside Where clause" can be a performance issue, as the function may be evaluated once for each result row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to make the `fn_GetWarehouse` and inline table valued function as well and join it on.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT 
         _Inventory.*
    FROM Inventory _Inventory
    join fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId) _Warehouse
        on _Warehouse.warehouse = _Inventory.Warehouse
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your return statement.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS TABLE AS
   RETURN SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Warehouse = fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId)
```

Alternately, you need begin and end to mark blocks of code for anything more than a single return statement, so:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ItemInventory] (@CustomerId)
RETURNS @tableName TABLE (<TableDefinition>) AS
BEGIN
   SET @Warehouse = fn_GetWarehouse(@CustomerId)
   INSERT INTO @TableName SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Warehouse = @Warehouse
   RETURN
END
```